# Adding multiple real estate properties to back end

Tags: custom-post-types

Client has a property management site. He wants clients to signup and enter rental each property into the system, with photos as well. These properties entries will not be accessible to public, but only to the user himself and the PM "admins".

I could create a custom content type, that would be pretty easy I suppose.

- How would I make them unpublished by default?
- How would I create Prop mgmt specific admins, who would be able edit listings as well, but not have access to any of the pages or posts or any other admin related things?

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign them different [roles and capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) using the native settings in WordPress like Contributor which only allows them to write and manage their own posts but cannot publish posts.